# Redirect standard error output on Unix

Tags: unix, standards

I created a folder, ABC. In this folder I created two files, file1 and file2. Next on the folder I set rw permissions for everybody. When I try `ls ABC` it prints:

```
/bin/ls: cannot access ABC/file2: Permission denied

/bin/ls: cannot access ABC/file1: Permission denied

file1  file2
```

I want to split this message into two parts and write to files success.txt and fail.txt. So in Bash, I tried something like:

```
ls ABC > success.txt 2> fail.txt
```

But in success.txt I have " file1 file2", but fail.txt is empty, so where are the first two lines of the message?

---

Thanks Arne and shellter for your interest. So I create the folder with:

```
mkdir ABC
```

Next:

```
 cd ABC
 touch file1 file2
```

Next:

```
cd ..
chmod 666 ABC
```

And when I enter `ls ABC` I get:

```
/bin/ls: cannot access ABC/file2: Permission denied

/bin/ls: cannot access ABC/file1: Permission denied

file1  file2
```

But when I write an sh script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
$* > success.txt 2> fail txt
```

fail.txt is empty. Why? I add that in another situation everything works, so the problem is only where the command prints information on both sterr and stdout.

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation. The redirection works fine for me. It would help if you could exactly write down how you created the folder and the files.

Comment: and, if inside of a script (This is a programming question, right?) add debugging output like `ls -l ABC/*` and `umask` and then modify your question above to contain the output of those commands. Maybe you should also edit your post to include the relevant sections of your script. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have `ls` defined as an alias or shell function.  Do you have something like

```
alias ls='/bin/ls -l'
```

in one of your startup files (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`)?

What is the output of

```
type -a ls
```

?

`ls ABC` by itself shouldn't give you those error messages; the `666` directory permissions won't prevent it from listing the names of the files.  Try `/bin/ls ABC` to confirm this.

Your alias or function isn't visible from a shell script.

Your syntax for directing stdout to one file and stderr to another is correct.  You're just running a command that doesn't write anything to stderr.

Incidentally, setting 666 permissions on a directory rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think your system has `ls` configured to use colour codes when output is to a terminal (via environment variable, alias or function). If colours are required, `ls` will `lstat` each file which requires search permission on the directory. Just listing the names of the files does not need search permission.

Comment: That's plausible -- except that then I'd expect the error messages to start with `ls:`, not `/bin/ls:`.  I think that `ls` is a function or alias that invokes `/bin/ls`.